# Check box value is not saving into database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am trying to save my checkbox value if checkbox select value will be 1 otherwise it will be 0.

But I don't know where I am wrong value is not saving into my database please look into my form.

My Form:

```
                <form id="preferences_form" role="form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/preference') }}" class="mujucet-registration">
                            <h5>Nastavení zpráv</h5>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label  for="ch1">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="monthly" id="ch1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Měsíční výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label >
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="weekly"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Týdenní přehled
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="tax_reviews"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Daňové výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="quarterly"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Čtvrtletní výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="annually"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Roční výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Novinky
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label class="border">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="direct_mail_reviews"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span> Chci výpisy zasílat také Poštou <span class="light">20 kč za výpis</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div><h5>Kontaktní preference</h5>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="email"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Email
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="sms"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>SMS
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

My Controller action where i am saving my values:

```
public function preferences(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();

    $preferences = new Preference();

    $preferences->userID = $user;
    $preferences->monthly = Input::get('monthly')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->weekly = Input::get('weekly')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->tax_reviews = Input::get('tax_reviews')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->quarterly = Input::get('quarterly')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->quarterly = Input::get('quarterly')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->annually = Input::get('annually')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->newsletter = Input::get('newsletter')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->direct_mail_reviews = Input::get('direct_mail_reviews')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->email = Input::get('email')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->sms = Input::get('sms')? 1 : 0;
    $preferences->save();

    return back();

}
```

I am using javascript code to save values with button:

```
submitForms = function(){
  document.getElementById("preferences_form").submit();
}
```

And my Model:

```
class Preference extends Model
   {
protected $table = 'db_preferences';
protected $fillable = ['userID','monthly','weekly','tax_reviews','quarterly','annually','newsletter','direct_mail_reviews','email','sms'];
   }
```

Please notify me where I am wrong your help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: i didnt see any error

Comment: Have you verified, right before you make the call to `$preferences->save();` in your controller, that all values are what you expect them to be? The issue could also be related to any constraints you may have on the database columns so if you could post those as well that would help. As a side note I'm not sure why you would use javascript to post the form when this could probably be achieved in the HTML directly, but with that said I'm not an expert on PHP or laravel

Comment: i need to save one more form with same button thats why i used javascript

Comment: I have set my type to int to all my values because i want to save value 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether a Check box has selected or not as bellow.

```
$preferences->monthly = Input::get('monthly') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
```

more simplified code

```
$preferences->monthly = Input::get('monthly') == 'on' ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add `value` attribute in all input field (whatever the field type is). Because It's safe.
- Don't use int for storing 1/0 in database. Becuase it's wasting the extra memory. Use tinyInt.

If you use tinyInt, this code may help you.

```
`$preferences->monthly = $request->has('monthly');
 $preferences->weekly = $request->has('weekly');`
```

Comment: Hi i used your above code and also change the type to tiny int but no working i cannot save my values into database

Comment: can you further help me on this?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `dd($request->all())`

Comment: i tried it but its not showing any response it refesh the page not adding values

Comment: can u come on chat or any other source where we can chat

Comment: if it refreshes the page again and not stop. That means your form request never landed that method(`preferences`). Check routes carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$request` doesn't return empty form element values, so your checkbox doesn't even show up in the array of form input values submitted. Therefore there's nothing to write to the database.

Adding this line to your controller `update` function before you save or update the `$request` data will set a 0 or 1 value if it's unchecked or checked. It looks to see if there's a returned element in the `$request` array. If there is, then the value should be checked, otherwise it's unchecked.

```
!$request->monthly ? $request["monthly"] = 0 : $request["monthly"] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$request` doesn't return empty form element values, so your checkbox doesn't even show up in the array of form input values submitted.

To handle this, create a Form Request and call `prepareForValidation()`.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation

```php
// Http/Requests/UpdatePreferenceRequest.php

/**
 * Prepare the data for validation.
 */
protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        'monthly' => $this->has('monthly'),
        'weekly' => $this->has('weekly'),
        # add your other inputs here
    ]);
}
```